# Unable to access request headers in decorator - django 4.0.4

Tags: python, django

Using class based views. I have a decorator that retrieves headers for verification. However I get this error accessing the request headers in the decorator:

> Decorator exception 'DetailsView' object has no attribute 'headers'

I must emphasize that accessing request headers in the view function works fine.

**View function:**

```
class DetailsView(View):

    @check_access
    def get(self, request):     
        res = {
            'status': 200,
            'response': 'heeaders test.',
            'test': 'okay'
        }
        return HttpResponse(JsonResponse(res, safe=False), content_type='text/json')
```

**Decorator:**

```
def check_access():
    def decorator(view_function):
        def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                print("headers", request.headers)
                return view_function(request, *args, **kwargs) 

            except Exception as e:
                return HttpResponse('Unauthorized', status=401)

        return wrap

    return decorator
```

Comment: It's happens because first argument in `wrap` function is `self`. So you should use `def wrap(self, request, *args, **kwargs): ...`

Answer (score 1):

Delete 'def check_access():' and Change decorate function to check_access.
And move 'self' argument.

in View Function

```
class DetailsView(View):
    @check_access
    def get(request): # Delete Self     
        ....
```

in decorator

```
def check_access(view_function):
    def wrap(self, request, *args, **kwargs): # add self
        ...
    return wrap
```

referenced site : [Decorator](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/#syntactic-sugar)